# spring cloud config server response very slow

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-config

My spring cloud config server response is very slow for every request, and the 
key point debug log which I found is here

```
2017-11-09 19:10:15,389org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolverFound key 'CommonProgramFiles(x86)' in [systemEnvironment] with type [String]
2017-11-09 19:**10:15,389**org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolverFound key 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS' in [systemEnvironment] with type [String]
2017-11-09 19:**10:16,764**org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironmentAdding [springCloudClientHostInfo] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2017-11-09 19:10:16,765org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironmentAdding [random] PropertySource with search precedence immediately lower than [systemEnvironment]
```

There is a delay of about one second for single request.

Here is the analysis result use Jprofiler when I request three times
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/555Md.png)
, from this I found the InetUtils take very long time, so I test the source code which I found from github in my localhost, the speed is really slow...

```
    try {
        int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nics = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces(); nics.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface ifc = nics.nextElement();
            if (ifc.isUp()) {
                log.trace("Testing interface: " + ifc.getDisplayName());
                if (ifc.getIndex() < lowest || result == null) {
                    lowest = ifc.getIndex();
                }
                else if (result != null) {
                    continue;
                }

                // @formatter:off
                if (!ignoreInterface(ifc.getDisplayName())) {
                    for (Enumeration<InetAddress> addrs = ifc
                            .getInetAddresses(); addrs.hasMoreElements();) {
                        InetAddress address = addrs.nextElement();
                        if (address instanceof Inet4Address
                                && !address.isLoopbackAddress()
                                && !ignoreAddress(address)) {
                            log.trace("Found non-loopback interface: "
                                    + ifc.getDisplayName());
                            result = address;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // @formatter:on
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error("Cannot get first non-loopback address", ex);
    }
```

does anybody know why?

Comment: which cloud service is used to host your config servers?

Comment: @ajc, I test it in my localhost, and use git repository which in LAN.